# Train TensorFlow Sequential model using soft labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification

How can I train a TensorFlow Sequential model using soft labels (vectors of p(Y_i|X)) instead of hard labels? e.g. instead of using `y = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]` I want to use `y = [[0.2, 0.8], [0.9, 0.1], [0.3, 0.7], [0.01, 0.99], [0.65, 0.35]]`.

I tried but I get this error:

```
ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 1) vs (None, 2)).
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @plumbe0 any feedback to the answer?